# Mongo db skip-limit work before match after unwind

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

This is my query:

```
db.getCollection('grades').
aggregate([{ "$match" : { "class_id" : 28, "student_id" : 0 } }, 
{ "$unwind" : "$scores" }, 
{ "$match" : { "scores.type" : "homework" } }, 
{ "$skip" : 3 }, { "$limit" : 3 }, 
{ "$group" : { "_id" : { "id" : "$_id" }, "scores" : { "$push" : "$scores" } } }, 
{ "$project" : { "_id" : "$_id.id", "scores" : 1 } }])
```

`scores` - is a nested array of objects. `Score object` - `{type: "someType", score: someScore}`. This query returns one document.

The problem: array of `scores` has 6 objects and 4 of them have type `homework`.

> The result, what I've received: http://prntscr.com/bq217r
>
> The original document: http://prntscr.com/bq23bv

Why `skip-limit` performed before `match` operator? How can I fix it?

Comment: haha mongoDb University problem???

Comment: Nope. But collection is from the university as I know))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per attached screenshot everything looks OK.

we have 4 elements    1   2   3   4, then we are skipping 3, so we get 4 at the end... and 53 is the value :-)

**btw** your skip/limit is **after** `$match`

Comment: Right... Need to delete the question. It was a very long day :(

Comment: no need to delete :-) someone will look for that:-)